# Swift 5 Shrinking / Growing Navigation Large Titles Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So I have a controller with a large titled navigation controller and UIScrollView. I'm trying to make the large title shrink / grow with it's natural movement (like when scrolled with finger on UI). I thought it listens and responds to the first vertical scroll view it finds but `setContentOffset` does not shrink the large title.

Here is what happens when I did `scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 30), animated: true)` :

[image: does not shrink]

And here is what happens when I scroll with finger on screen :

[image: shrinks with UI scroll]

**Note that I don't want to simulate the grow / shrink movement using** `UIView.animate` **with**

`navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never`

**or**

`navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

Here goes the question : Is it possible to programmatically to shrink / grow the navigation bar large title with its natural movement or are there any workarounds (like setting content offset of the scroll view but that didn't work) ?